# Multiplicity of an Eigenvalue of the Exponential of an Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $T:\mathbf R^n\to\mathbf R^n$ be a linear operator.
>   Then $$\det e^T=e^{\text{Trace}(T)}$$

To do this I took the following apporach.

Let $\lambda\in\mathbf R$ be an eigenvalue of $T$.
Then $Tv=\lambda v$ for some nonzero vector $v\in \mathbf R^n$.

Noting that $e^Tv=e^\lambda v$, we get that $e^\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $e^T$.

So I now try to show that the multiplicity of $\lambda$ for $T$ is same as the multiplicity of $e^\lambda$ for $e^T$.

To do that I need to show that $\dim \ker(T-\lambda I)^n=\dim \ker(e^T-e^\lambda I)^n$.

But I have no idea how to go further.

Can anybody help?

(I have seen a proof of the above mentioned result using a completely different approach but still it would be of some importance to explicitly establish the fact that, if it is true, the multiplicity of $\lambda$ for $T$ is same as the multiplicity of $e^\lambda$ for $e^T$).

Comment: Do you have Jordan canonical form?

Comment: @JHance I know about the Jordan canonical form but I have always avoided using it. It never crosses my mind. Thanks for the prompt. I'll try using that. Also, daw has posted a nice answer below. You may want to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assume $\lambda=0$. Take $v\in ker(T)^n$. We have to show $v\in ker(T-I)^n$.
Then
$$
(e^T-I)v =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k!}T^kv=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac1{k!}T^kv.
$$
We prove per Induction that
$$
(e^T-I)^j v = T^j p_j(T)v,
$$
where $p_j$ is a polynomial. Assume that this claim is true for all $j$ with $1\le j\le n-1$.
Then
$$
(e^T-I)^{j+1} =(e^T-I) T^j p_j(T)v =  T^j p_j(T) (e^T-I)v = T^{j+1} p_j(T)p_1(T)v.
$$
Setting $p_{j+1}:=p_1p_j$ finishes the induction. Hence it follows $(e^T-I)^nv=0$.
This proves $ker(T)^n \subset ker(e^T-I)^n$.

Second, let $\lambda\ne0$. Set $\tilde T:=T-\lambda I$. 
Then $e^{\tilde T} = e^{T-\lambda I} = e^{-\lambda}e^T$ as $T$ and $I$ commute.
From the first step, it follows
$$
ker(T-\lambda I)^n = ker(\tilde T)^n\subset ker(e^{\tilde T}-I  )^n
= ker(e^{-\lambda}e^T-I)^n = ker(e^T-e^\lambda I)^n.
$$

Answer (score 1):

@ caffeinemachine , your required equality (concerning the kernels) is true if $spectrum(T)\subset\mathbb{R}$ (because $\exp$ is injective over $\mathbb{R}$) but, otherwise, is false. A priori, $T$ admits non-real eigenvalues ; how do you proceed with them ?

To show (*): $\det(e^T)=e^{tr(T)}$, there are $2$ methods.

1. Staying over $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $\dfrac{d}{dt}\log(\det(e^{tT}))=tr(T)$. You must know the derivative of "$\det$".
2. Going up over $\mathbb{C}$. Use the fact that $T$ is similar to a triangular matrix $U$ and calculate the diagonal of $e^U$. Thus we obtain the eigenvalues of $e^T$ with multiplicity and therefore we deduce (*). Moreover this method is valid for any matrix function $f$ instead of $\exp$ (cf. Matrix functions, Higham).

Comment: Yes. They may be no real eigenvalues of T at all. In that case I hope to formulate an argument via eigenpairs. How to go about doing that is not clear to me now. But I am sure there is interesting mathematics lying behind it.

Comment: Even if I am ultimately unable to make argue via eigenpairs, it is interesting that the multiplicity of a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$ is same as the multiplicity of $e^\lambda$ of $e^T$.

Comment: @ caffeinemachine, have a look at this well-known example: $T:=\begin{pmatrix}0&-2\pi\\2\pi&0\end{pmatrix}$; then $e^T=I_2$.

Comment: @ caffeinemachine  your assertion "it is interesting that the multiplicity of a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$ is same as the multiplicity of $e^λ$ of $e^T$" is valid only if there are no non-real eigenvalues. For instance $T=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&-2\pi\\0&2\pi&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I just saw this. Give me sometime to think. Sorry for the late response.